# Why struts2-junit plugin complains about convention plugin in?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, junit, struts2

I have a running project in Maven, Struts 2. I'm trying to add struts2-junit-plugin for testing.

So I added the plugin for struts2-junit.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.20</version>
</dependency>
```

After I run, I got this error:

```xml
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext
```

Then I added the plugin for jsp-api.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>prototype</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I ran it, I got a different error:

```xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/content/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I tried to do the following change to my `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF"
```

But it also did not work.

When I remove the `struts2-convention-plugin` from my pom file, it works.

But I need the struts2-convention-plugin. Can any one tell that what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution with help of one of my friend, I did not use this line
`<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF"` in struts.xml....

but i created folder structure `WEB_INF/content/user-actions` inside `src/main/resources` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong version and a scope in dependency. Replace with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And use the default configuration for results' path

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was resolved by adding below line in struts.xml

`<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/" />`